# Pandas: how to remove duplicate rows, but keep ALL rows with max value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can I remove duplicate rows, but keep ALL rows with the max value. For example, I have a dataframe with 4 rows:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},{'a': 7, 'b': 10, 'c': 2}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

From this dataframe, I want to have a dataframe like (3 rows, group by 'a', keep all rows that have max value in 'c'):

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with Boolean indexing:

```
res = df[df['c'] == df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')]

print(res)

   a  b   c
0  1  2   3
1  7  2  20
2  7  2  20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the `max` c per group using `groupby` and `transform` and then filter where your record is equal to the max like:

```
df['max_c'] = df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')
df[df['c']==df['max_c']].drop(['max_c'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I replace the second command with df = df.loc[df['c'] == df['max_c']] then it works.

Comment: Welcome! Accept the answer if it solved the question.